# Loop through a multi value entity reference field working only on the first selected item

Tags: 8, nodes, webforms

1) I have an entity reference view `articles_per_user` listing all nodes of type `article` authored by the current logged in user.

2) On the Article Entity, there is a taxonomy reference field `field_article_country` referencing the taxonomy vocabulary: "Countries" (One value is allowed)

3) On the User Entity, there is a multi-value taxonomy reference field `field_user_article_countries` referencing the same taxonomy vocabulary: "Countries" (Unlimited value are allowed)

4) On a Webform, I have an entity reference field `articles` referencing the above entity reference view 'articles_per_user' with unlimited values where the users can select one or more article.

5) When Webform is submitted, I want to:

1. Load each selected Article.
2. Get value of the `field_article_country`
3. Load the current logged in user entity.
4. Set the retrieved value to `field_user_article_countries`
5. Save the User entity.

**Quick Demonstration:**

Say the `Current User` selected on the Webform 3 articles where:

- **Article 1** has `field_article_country` = United States
- **Article 2** has `field_article_country` = Egypt
- **Article 3** has `field_article_country` = Spain

After the Webform is submitted, the `field_user_article_countries` at the User Entity must have 3 values selected:

- United States
- Egypt
- Spain

**The error I am facing** is at `field_user_article_countries`, I see only one value selected:

- United States

**Below is my code:**

```
// Function to be fired while submitting the Webform.
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {

    // Load the account of current logged in user.
    $CurrentUid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
    $CurrentUser = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($CurrentUid);

    // Get the selected 'Articles' Value.
    $ArticleIDs = $values['articles'];     // NIDs

    // Load all "Articles" according to their IDs.
    $Articles = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($ArticleIDs);

    // Loop through loaded articles entities.
    foreach ($Articles as $Article) {

    // Get the "Article Country" Value from the loaded article.
    $ArticleCountry = $Article->get('field_article_country')->target_id;

    // Set the 'User Country' value on the user account.
    $CurrentUser->set('field_user_article_countries', $ArticleCountry);
    }

    // Save the User account.
    $CurrentUser->save();

}
```

Comment: Cause your `set` is overidding it on each loop iteration rather than adding to it.

Comment: @NoSssweat can you please provide an example on how I can add the values rather than override them ?

Comment: `$CurrentUser->field_user_article_countries[] = ['target_id' => $ArticleCountry];`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, can you please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($Articles as $Article) {

  // Get the "Article Country" Value from the loaded article.
  $ArticleCountry = $Article->field_article_country->target_id; // shorter way

  // Set the 'User Country' value on the user account.
  $CurrentUser->field_user_article_countries[] = ['target_id' => $ArticleCountry]; // use array

}
```